# Making a Class Evaluate an Expression Not Working in Angular App

Tags: angular

I am running into an issue where a class I want to apply in my Angular app when info is missing is not working correctly. When I try this:

```
<h2 [class.invalid]="!isContactInfoValidated()">Contact<h2>
```

... I get an error: `isContactInfoValidated() is not a function`. And this is the case even though it's defined in my component like this (simple return for testing):

```
// Really simple boolean example for testing
isContactInfoValidated() {
  return false;
}
```

Now, conversely, I can do this with no problem:

```
  <h2 [class.invalid]="!this.customer.contacts.length">Contacts</h2>
```

So, what is the problem with my first example? I can assign this to evaluate a boolean function, correct? Anyone see the problem here?

Comment: what is `this`in the second example?

Comment: This works fine for me. You must be missing something else.

Comment: This should work just fine, although many will tell you it's bad practice to bind method calls in the template. Are you sure the template and the class are configured for the same component?

Comment: As I thought, this should work. The error is not helpful here.

Comment: Yeah, the error doesn't make sense, sometimes you get such errors if there is something wrong in the template after the actual expression too.. try checking your html after this method is called

Comment: I just tried it in a stackblitz and it does not generate an error for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvbfej

Comment: Yeah, thanks, must have been an error bubbling up from elsewhere.